# Laravel Storage download returns blank page/wrong Header

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I try to download an xlsx-File with Laravel Storage:

```
    $header = [
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'
    ];
    //dd(Storage::exists('invoices.xlsx')); // true
    return Storage::download('invoices.xlsx', 'invoices.xlsx', $header);
```

It returns a blank page (local & live System) with the following Header:

```
host: 127.0.0.1:8000
date: Wed, 15 Nov 2022 18:31:14 GMT; Wed, 15 Nov 2022 18:31:14 GMT
connection: close
x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.14
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how are u making the request? if u r doing it via Inertia `<Link>`, don't. Use `<a>`

Comment: For this time a direct GET-Request via URL.

Comment: u tried to do it without the headers? just to check

Comment: @ericmp - yes, same result!

Comment: and if u do `dd(Storage::get('invoices.xlsx'));` what u get?

Comment: Seems like the file: b"PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00ËapUGÆD▓Z\x01\x00\x00­\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml¡ö╦N├0\x10E¸|Eõ-J£▓@\x085Ýé┬\x12*Q>`░'ìUÃÂl¸§¸LÆûùÈ@ònbE±¢gr=Ò±tWÙdâ>(k6╩rûá\x11V*│,Ï█Ô)¢cIê`$hk░`{\fl:╣\x1A/÷\x0ECBb\x13V┼Þ¯9\x0Fó┬\x1ABf\x1D\x1A·RZ_CñW┐õ\x0E─û╚o‗³û\vk"ÜÿããâMã/─¸Jb2\x07\x1Fƒí&\f▀i\x1E╔╗þ(#?û<t┬å]0pN+\x01æþ\e#\x7FQS[ûJá┤b]ô$km«\e\x17~\x12\x18Ô^c\x18î╬#╚P!ãZgØÚæ<├\x12Í:&Å;r´2¸¿├y╝Cÿ\x19)█=íR«Åð .................

Comment: lets continue debugging xd. and if u do `dd(Storage::download('invoices.xlsx', 'invoices.xlsx', $header))`?

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse {#1444 ▼
  #callback: Closure() {#1554 ▶}
  #streamed: false
  -headersSent: false
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#1529 ▼
    #headers: array:5 [▼
      "content-type" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/vnd.ms-excel"
      ]
      "content-length" => array:1 [▶]
      "content-disposition" => array:1 [▶]
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
      "date" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"

Comment: so are u sure if u dont go to the url and do the request u dont get the file downloaded? this is really weird

Comment: @ericmp - yes I try only the direct URL. I use Inertia.js - could that be a problem? But the request is routed Laravel only!

Comment: if u go directly via url (full page reload), Inertia isn't the issue here

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I've called the download function from another function without return :-(

Comment: oh god, well.. sometimes happens (: